# Rounding up a number not always works as expected

Tags: ios6, rounding-error, rounding

I want to charge my users 1 credit for each hour or fraction they use a service.
To calculate the cost I'm using the following code, but in some cases, for example when the starting and ending dates are exactly at one day difference, I get a cost of 25 credits instead of 24:

```
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[format setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[format setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];
[format setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
[format setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
NSTimeInterval ti = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
float costValue = ti/3600;
self.cost = [format stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:costValue]];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTimeInterval` has sub-millisecond precision. If the dates are one day and a millisecond apart, you would charge the 25-th credit.

Changing the code to do integer division should deal with the problem:

```
// You do not need sub-second resolution here, because you divide by 
// the number of seconds in the hour anyway
NSInteger ti = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
NSInteger costValue = (ti+3599)/3600;
// At this point, the cost is ready. You do not need a special formatter for it.
```

Comment: I've tried your code, but it's not working as I intended. For example, if the start date is today at 4:00 PM and the end date is today at 4:02 PM, it's not counting 1 credit. Same thing, f the difference is 1 hour and, say, 3 minutes, it's only counting 1 credit.

Comment: @Aleph72 The you can use the trick for rounding up integer division (see the edit).

Comment: Ok, the trick works. But I don't understand why. Could you explain it, please?

Comment: I've talked too early. If the dates difference is exactly 24 hours, I get 25 credits...

Comment: By the way, the two dates are taken from a UIDatePicker, don't know if this changes something.

Comment: @Aleph72 The reason the trick works is that when you add any positive number between `1` and `3599` to the `3599` constant, the sum will be in the `3600..7199` range, so dividing it by `3600` will always be `1`.

Comment: @Aleph72 If the division resulted in 25 instead of 24, then the time difference had been at least a day and one second. The picker does not show you seconds, but you can check it with `NSLog("%d", ti)` in the example above. You can fix this by adding, say, `3540` instead of `3599`. This will round down anything less than one minute, and round up anything with a minute or more.

Comment: Ok, now it's perfectly working. Thank you very much @dasblinkenlight